# What is the best way to create an invisible vertical list in docbook for xsl-fo?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, docbook

I'm writing docbook and applying the xsl-fo transformation to produce a pdf.

Instead of listing items in a comma separated list, "item1, item2, item" I would like them in a vertical list, but without any markup whatsoever, i.e. without frames, indentation bullets etc. What's the best way to accomplish this? I've tried using an itemizedlist without marker, i.e.
`<itemizedlist mark="none"><listitem>item1</listitem></itemizedlist>`

but the content gets indented by the attribute provisional-distance-between-starts. Trying to set this to zero resulted in overconstrained errors from fop. Any other way to accomplish this? Work with an informaltable and try to turn off all table and cell frames, indentation etc? More ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Customize an element (of your choice) and use a role to indicate it is your customized version of that element. In that customization layer, you would add the formatting attributes you desire for your enhancement. Or add a new element (again of your choice) and set its visual attributes. See http://www.docbook.org/tdg51/en/html/ch05.html, specifically adding elements.